# Receiving a Floating Point value in bytes in Java

Tags: java, floating-point

I am receiving a floating point value over USB, in bytes. How do I bring that value in as a floating point number. Keep in mind it is actually a float point number, I'm just receiving it as byte at a time via USB.  MSB first.

```
    USB_ByteArray[3] = 42
    USB_ByteArray[2] = 99
    USB_ByteArray[1] = 99
    USB_ByteArray[0] = 9A
```

How do I represent the above byte value as the floating point number they represent?

76.8 = 0x4299999a (IEEE Floating Point )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [`Float.intBitsToFloat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat(int)). Assuming the encoding used is IEEE 754, you create an int from the byte values and can use that method to convert it to a float.

Example using jshell:

```
axel@xiaolong ~ % jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 14
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> Float.intBitsToFloat(0x4299999a)
$1 ==> 76.8
```

Comment: Hi Axel  Thanks for responding.  Here is the issue, I need to bring the bytes in 1st, and store them somewhere.  So I put them into an integer value, by shifting, and if I use Float.inBitsToFloat it will think the value is an int value and just cast it but thats not correct the value is already a floating point value so no casting is needed.

Comment: Look at the example. It takes the int value 0x4299999a and converts it to float. No casting needed.

Comment: that is correct I just saw that, OK let me try it out